# error in create graph: unexpected attribute 'x'

Tags: python

I am trying to to create graph using this data below:

[image]

```
from bokeh.charts import Scatter
p = Scatter(test, x='xlabel', y='age', color='click', legend='top_left')
show(p)
```

but when I run the code I receive this

> unexpected attribute 'x'

note: I am using Jupyter notebook

Comment: What does `test` variable contain? Is it array or something else?

Comment: Did you try omitting x and y arguments? If you need to label you should use `xlabel` and `ylabel` instead.

Comment: not array. it is CSV file.

Comment: still not working unexpected attribute 'color'

Comment: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference/charts.html#bokeh.charts.Scatter

Comment: > In addition the the parameters specific to this chart, userguide_charts_generic_arguments are also accepted as keyword parameters.

Comment: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.8.1/docs/user_guide/charts.html#generic-arguments

Comment: ok thanks I will try it

Comment: still the same problem